# Assert from dll in_ASSERTE(__acrt_first_block == header) during vector de-allocation in DEBUG mode only

Tags: c++, dll

I have created MyComm.dll in c++, following is the psudo code of dll.

```
/* CommLayerIF.h */

#include "CommLayerImpl.h"

enum class COMM_LAYER
{
    COMM_LAYER1,
    COMM_LAYER2
}

typedef std::vector<COMM_LAYER> CommLayers;

CommLayerIF*
CreateCommLayerIFInstance()
{
    return new CommLayerIF();
}

class CommLayerIF
{
public:
    /*! \brief Constructor
     */
     CommLayerIF();

    /*! \brief Destructor
     */
    virtual
    ~CommLayerIF() override;

    __declspec(dllexport) 
    int
    SetLayers(CommLayers CommunicationLayers);
private:
    CommLayerImpl* m_commLayerImpl;
};
```

Following is the implementation of CommLayerIf

/* CommLayerIF.cpp */

```
#include "CommLayerIF.h"    

int
CommLayerIF::SetLayers(CommLayers CommunicationLayers)
{
    //This function only reads vector and creates layers. It asserts after return.
    int status = m_commLayerImpl.SetLayers(CommLayers); 

    return status;
}
```

- Following is the application loading this DLL dynamically.

/* MyApp.cpp */

```
#include "CommLayerIF.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
{
    //Create comm layer instance from dll
    CommLayerIF *pComm = CreateCommLayerIFInstance();
    std::vector<COMM_LAYER> commLayers;
    commLayers.resize(2);
    commLayers[0] = COMM_LAYER::COMM_LAYER1;
    commLayers[1] = COMM_LAYER::COMM_LAYER2;

    int status = pComm->SetLayers(commLayers); 
    ....
}
```

The SetCommLayers(CommLayers) API taking vector by value and it internally passes the vector to another function. The application links the dll dynamically and calls SetCommLayer() API, but while returning from the API it asserts during vector deallocation with following reason from debug_heap.cpp,

_ASSERTE(__acrt_first_block == header);

Note: This issue is catched in Debug mode. I have tried to build application and Dll with Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) options, But still it asserts in Debug mode.
Please let me know why its failing? Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: _This code is working fine in Release mode, but asserts in Debug mode._ This might be a mis-belief. asserts are effective in debug mode only. Not alerting the issue in release doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: I agree. i will correct the sentence. But why it is failing? i am simply sending vector by value?

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. It's hard to guess with that little info.

Comment: Updated source code example

Comment: Did you consider that you have either to run debug DLL with debug appl. or release DLL with release appl? Mixing could become fatal. AFAIK, there is no guarantee that debug and release of a `std::vector` can be mixed. Furthermore, both have to be compiled with same version of MSVC++.

Comment: Ohh. I did silly mistake. I have changed settings to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd). But not in Debug configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Scheff. Now its workig fine after changing debug settings to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) for both Dll and Application.